# Datepicker when show, select date first

Tags: java, android, datepicker, actionlistener

I have an EditText, and when i click on this, he show adatepicker .
I wish that when I click on my editText , the date appears in the first choice , and after the selection of the month and day.

this is my code, a simply listener

```
    date.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {

                mYear = myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                //add+1 month, mycalendar start at month 0
                mmMonth = myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                mMonth = mmMonth + 1;
                mDayOfMonth = myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


                final DatePickerDialog mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(Register.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    //method for setDate to edit text
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                        //set edittext to selected date by user
                        if (year <= (mYear - 18) && date.toString().length() >= 5) {
                            date.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + monthOfYear + "/" + year);
                            setAnnee(mYear);
                            setMois(mMonth);
                            setJour(mDayOfMonth);
                            date.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        } else {
                            date.setText("wrong");
                            date.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            setAnnee(0);
                            setMois(0);
                            setJour(0);
                        }
                    }

                }, mYear, mMonth, mDayOfMonth);
                mDatePicker.setTitle("Select birthday date");

                mDatePicker.show();

            }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T82zQ.png)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: someone has an idea ?